# Comparing values obtained from combo box to another string fails even though both appear to be the same

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am trying to obtain a date from 3 separate combo boxes that I then convert to ints and make a Date object. However, when I compare this date string to an already existing string, it doesnt match even though in the debugger it appears to be the same. I have setup a simple if statement to check what the problem is however I am not sure why it does not match.

```
int apptDay, apptMonth, apptYear;
apptDay = Integer.parseInt(consultationDay.getSelectedItem().toString());
apptMonth = Integer.parseInt(consultationMonth.getSelectedItem().toString());
apptYear = Integer.parseInt(consultationYear.getSelectedItem().toString());
consultationDate = new Date(apptDay, apptMonth, apptYear);



if (appointmentList.get(0).getDate() == consultationDate) {
    sopl("Working");
}
```

I am quite sure that there is some issue with my code related to combo boxes as that is the only place where I face problems. The if statement is never satisfied so "Working" is never printed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use .equals instead of == to compare the two dates. Using == basically checks if they are pointing to the same object.

Comment: In Java, there is a difference between object equality (`.equals()` method) and object identity (`==` operator). It's like twins: their appearance might be equal, but they are two individuals, each with their own identity.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation it was helpful. However, in my solution I tried it with .equals as well but it still does not match even though both strings appear to be the same "01/01/2022"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **.equlas()** instead of the == operator.

```
int apptDay = 5, apptMonth = 12, apptYear = 2000;
Date testDate = new Date(apptDay, apptMonth, apptYear);
Date consultationDate = new Date(apptDay, apptMonth, apptYear);

if (testDate == consultationDate) {
    System.out.println("Success for ==");
} else if (testDate.equals(consultationDate)) {
    System.out.println("Success for equals");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I just tried it with .equals() however it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide the output if you print your Dates? System.out.println(consultationDate) and appointmentList.get(0).getDate()

Comment: Update: it worked I just needed to convert them to strings. Thank you for your solution! I just needed to convert them to strings and use .equals to compare.